# Graphviz/ Table/ How to merge cells

Tags: cell, graphviz

I would like to draw a graph like this -

[image: Expected graph]

I have Graphviz code like this -

```
digraph G {
    
    
"test" [
    label = <<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="darkorange">TEST</td>
        <td port="f1" border="1" bgcolor="darkorange"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="f2" border="1" bgcolor="cyan">A</td>
                 <td>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr><td port="f3" border="1" bgcolor="azure">A1</td></tr>
                        <tr><td port="f4" border="1" bgcolor="azure">A2</td></tr>
                        <tr><td port="f5" border="1" bgcolor="azure">A3</td></tr>                         
                    </table>
                </td>      
    </tr>          
    <tr>
        <td port="f5" border="1" bgcolor="gray">Else</td>
        <td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="gray"></td>
    </tr>
</table>>
shape = "none"
];

    
}
```

But it gives the graph like this

[image: output of the above graphviz code]

Would you please suggest how can we tweak the code to achieve the objective - merging f0, f1 on top and f5,f6 at bottom?

Comment: If you have not already done so, please take the [tour]. And welcome to Stack Overflow, also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML `<td>`s with `colspan` and `rowspan` attributes in GraphViz.  These allow one cell to span multiple columns and/or rows inside a table.

This also simplifies your digraph, as only one table is needed.

```
digraph G {
    
    
"test" [
    label = <<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="darkorange">TEST</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3" port="f5" border="1" bgcolor="blue">A</td>
        <td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="grey">Else</td>
    </tr>
</table>>
shape = "none"
];
    
}
```

This gives you the following basic output, which you can then customize for spacing, line colors, etc:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one also works. what's is the difference?

```
    digraph G {


    "test" [
        label = <<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr><td colspan="2" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="darkorange">TEST</td> </tr>
        <tr><td rowspan="4" port="f5" border="1" bgcolor="blue">A</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A1</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A2</td></tr>
        <tr><td port="f6" border="1" bgcolor="white">A3</td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="2" port="f0" border="1" bgcolor="grey">Else</td></tr>
        </table>>
    shape = "none"
    ];

}
```

Comment: In your version you have provided inconsistent values: (1) the cell with `A` in it has `rowspan="4"` - but in reality that cell only spans 3 rows - the ones containing `A1`, `A2` and `A3`. However, you also have (2) an extra `<tr>` row defined in your approach - also for the `A` cell. The HTML renderer does its best to make sense of (1) and (2), when interpreting the `rowspan` and `colspan` directives. It ends up looking the same as my solution. The two inconsistencies cancel each other out.